# Password Hash - External drive encrypted with Disk Utility

Tags: macos, disk-utility, external-disk, encryption

don't laugh, but I have encrypted my external drive and cannot remember the password.

The good thing is, the password was really bad (only four digits), so I could get it with brute force. You don't have to tell me that it is ridiculous to encrypt a drive with such a weak password. I do know this. I just don't know anymore why I encrypted the drive. Probably just because I could

For the brute force I already downloaded John the Ripper. My problem is that I don't know where to get the password hash from the drive. With google I only could find tutorials how to get the hash for Windows or Mac user accounts. But this was not helpful.

Can anyone tell me where to get the hash?

I am working with OS X High Sierra 10.13.3 and the drive is a WD Elements external drive.

thanks in advance

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

The disk encryption employed by Disk Utility does not store your password as a hash. Thus is there no hash to get, and John the Ripper is not the right program for brute forcing this type of encryption.

For File Vault encrypted disks, you could look at a program such as VileFault to try brute forcing the passphrase.

Comment: Oh ok. What program do you recommend for this issue?

Comment: I have added my recommendation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. But to be honest I did not get it work. I downloaded VileFault but it did not work (probably I am just to stupid to get it work )

Here is what it said:

`My-MBP:~ Basti$ /Users/Basti/Downloads/VileFault-master/vfdecrypt/Makefile ; exit;
clang: error: no such file or directory: '='
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'gcc'
clang: error: no input files`

Comment: Sounds like you have downloaded the source code for VileFault instead of a ready-to-run program. In order to convert the source code to a program, you'll to have development tools installed (compiler, linker, etc.). An easy way to do so is to install Apple Xcode from the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this was four years ago but I am working on a project that would help if you still need it, or just to share what I've found. I have a drive that I forgot the password to but remembered generally what it was, so I could make a file with a few thousand possibilities using a python script. After that you can use bash and the built in disk manager, disk utility, on in terminal diskutil and write a script that tries all the passcodes from your file. There's another stackexchange that talks about what I have just said as well.